# swift NSURLConnetction not working

Tags: http, swift, connection

I am new to the swift. Just couldn't get the below code working on the http request. Other than printing "start...", it doesn't print anything else. All the connection methods seem not called at all? Any suggestions?

```
class Network {
    var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    func getAcctSummary() {
        let urlAcctSummary = "http://www.google.com"
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlAcctSummary)
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)

        connection.start()

        println("started...")
    }//getAcctSummary

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("Failed with error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        println("didReceiveResponse")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData conData: NSData!) {
        self.data.appendData(conData)
        println("here 1")
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        println(self.data)
        println("here")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine which optional protocol methods are supported, the NSURLConnection delegate is required to be a subclass of NSObject.  Change the first line to:

```
class Network : NSObject {
```

And you should be good-to-go

Answer (score 0):

Try using swift NSURLSession. Worked best for me here is some ex code but had to pull out my custom code.

```
        func someFunc() ->()
        {
                 var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                 var personURL = "URL"

                 let url = NSURL(string:personURL)

                 var task:NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler:apiHandler)
                 task.resume()
        }
        func apiHandler(data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error:NSError!)
        {

               if error
               {
                   println("API error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
               }

              var jsonError:NSError?

              var json:JMSMediaDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as Dictionary

             println(json)

            //do stuff with data

}
```